# Get a loop value in jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {    
    $("#results").on("click", "#source_" + array[i], function(event) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('i : ' + i); // here i equal table.length, always
     });
}
```

Imagine the `<div id="results">` has been triggered by a previous javascript action.

If array.lenght = 10, and if I click on `<element id="source_5">`, the function alerts `10`.

How to get the array value of the clicked element, `5` in this example ?

Comment: what do you mean `value of clicked element`?

Comment: for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {    
    $("#results").on("click", "#source_" + array[i], {num : i}, function(event) {  
        event.preventDefault();
        alert('i : ' + event.data.num);
     });